# Integral identity for squared difference of ratio and inverse ratio on the positive axis

Tags: calculus, integration

Could anyone provide change of variables or proof of the functional identity:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f((\frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{x})^2)dx = a \int_{0}^{\infty}f(y^2)dy$$
The simple change of variables $y = \frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{x}$ and $dy/dx = 1/a+b/x^2$ has not been successful, which further does not yield the correct limits.

Comment: are you sure that there is no typo?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\alpha t$ ($\alpha>0$) and then
$$ \frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{x}=\frac{\alpha t}{a}-\frac{b}{\alpha t}.$$
Let $\frac{\alpha}{a}=\frac{b}{\alpha}$ and then $\alpha=\sqrt{ab}$. So under $x\to x-\frac1x$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}f((\frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{x})^2)dx\\
&=&\sqrt{ab}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(\frac{b}{a}(x-\frac{1}{x})^2)dx\tag{1}\\
&=&\sqrt{ab}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}f(\frac{b}{a}(x-\frac{1}{x})^2)dx\tag{2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Adding (1) and (2) and under $y=x-\frac{1}{x}$ and $y\to\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}y$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
2I&=&\sqrt{ab}\int_{0}^{\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x^2})f(\frac{b}{a}(x-\frac{1}{x})^2)dx\\
&=&\sqrt{ab}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\frac{b}{a}y^2)dy\\
&=&2\sqrt{ab}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(\frac{b}{a}y^2)dy\\
&=&2a\int_0^{\infty}f(y^2)dy
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I=a\int_0^{\infty}f(y^2)dy. $$

Comment: This is the Cauchy-Schlömilch integral transformation.